# Import "Crypto.Cipher" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports) in VSCode intel MAC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, cryptography, pycrypto, pycryptodome

I've pip installed the ones that i need as I viewed the documentation and other websites. How come it still says that my module is not found?

Here are my imports

```
import socket
import random
import hashlib

from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4

#from Crypto.Cipher import AES

#from Crypto.Hash import SHA256, HMAC
#from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
```

here is my pip list on vs code. My terminal also already has all of these

```
Package                   Version
------------------------- ---------
certifi                   2023.7.22
cffi                      1.15.1
charset-normalizer        3.2.0
crypto                    1.4.1
cryptography              41.0.3
idna                      3.4
Naked                     0.1.32
pip                       23.2.1
pycparser                 2.21
pycryptodome              3.18.0
pycryptodome-test-vectors 1.0.12
pycryptodomex             3.18.0
PyYAML                    6.0.1
requests                  2.31.0
setuptools                68.0.0
shellescape               3.8.1
urllib3                   2.0.4
```

this is the error reflected in the vscode terminal

```
 File "/Users/bbbb/Downloads/alice.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

I tried pip installing everything i needed from seeing other stack overflow questions. I've restarted my vscode many times too. nothing seemed to work

Comment: I don't know what happens if you have *both* `pycryptodome` and `pycryptodomex` installed, but try using the `Cryptodome` module instead, e.g. `from Cryptodome.Cipher import ARC4`

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk-Strike it says this. Import "Cryptodome.Cipher" could not be resolved Pylance :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg guys. if yall have this problem. I resolved it by playing around in my environment.

Simply press command+shift+p.
Select python:select interpreter.
select the global one. if it doesnt work, try the others one by one!

Mine finally worked... after 2 days... yays!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).